# Play random sounds without repeat

Tags: javascript, playsound

I'm looking to have an image, that when clicked plays a sound clip (from a list of sound clips) without repeating the same clip (until the user goes through the whole list of sounds.)

At the moment my code works but plays any one of my sound clips randomly and repeats a lot.

If anyone knows how to tweak this to make it play every clip in the list at least once before repeating that would be brilliant!

This is the code I'm using at the moment:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function playSounds() {
    var sounds = [
        "AUDIO URL",
        "AUDIO URL",
        "AUDIO URL",
        "AUDIO URL",
        "AUDIO URL"
    ];

    var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (sounds.length));
    $("#element").html("<embed src=\"" + sounds[index] + "\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"true\" />");
}
</script>

<a onclick="playSounds()"><img src="IMAGE URL" width="300px" id="ImageButton1"></a>
```

I'm guessing it's something to do with the `Math.random()` part of the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Array as playlist and maintain the played sounds in a second array. Check my [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jkutianski/QqZ6y/5/)

```
<a onclick="playSounds()">
   <img src="http://www.stephaniequinn.com/Ani-Piano.gif" width="300px" id="ImageButton1">
</a>
<div id="element"></div>
<script>
var sounds = ["http://www.stephaniequinn.com/Music/Allegro%20from%20Duet%20in%20C%20Major.mp3",
              "http://www.stephaniequinn.com/Music/Canon.mp3",
              "http://www.stephaniequinn.com/Music/Handel%20Royal%20Fireworks%20-%2007.mp3",
              "http://www.stephaniequinn.com/Music/Commercial%20DEMO%20-%2009.mp3"],
    oldSounds = [];

var playSounds = function () {
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (sounds.length)),
        thisSound = sounds[index];

        oldSounds.push(thisSound);
        sounds.splice(index, 1);

        if (sounds.length < 1) {
            sounds = oldSounds.splice(0, oldSounds.length);
        }

        $("#element").html("<audio autoplay><source src=\"" + thisSound + "\" type=\"audio/mpeg\"><embed src=\"" + thisSound + "\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"true\" /></audio>");
}
</script>
```

Comment: Brilliant, this is spot on what I was looking for!

Comment: Hi, do you know how I can get this code to work on tablets and mobile browsers too? Does it have to be in HTML5?

Comment: I change the code to use the HTML5 Audio element too. Remenber that not all the browsers support MP3.

Comment: How would I do that? Sorry I have no clue with this!

Comment: Check the audio formats for browsers [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Supported_media_formats)

Comment: This is the code I'm using http://jsfiddle.net/adamsears/kZF9T/ - which won't work on mobile/tablet

Comment: Check [this page](http://pupunzi.open-lab.com/2013/03/13/making-html5-audio-actually-work-on-mobile/)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't ran the following code but the outline should be enough. This will always play the sounds in random order. The steps are:

1. generate the random indices in a loop until we found one that has not been played yet
2. when we find one that's not been played add it to an array for future reference and play it
3. we know we've played all of the sounds when the array's length equals that of the sounds' array. At this point we empty the array and carry on.

   ```
   var playedSounds = [];

   var sounds = [
       "AUDIO URL",
       "AUDIO URL",
       "AUDIO URL",
       "AUDIO URL",
       "AUDIO URL"
   ];

   function hasPlayed(sound) {

       if (playedSounds.length == sounds.length) {

           // We've played all of the sounds. Reset and start again.
           playedSounds = [];
           playedSounds.push(sound);
           return false;

       }

       // We haven't played all the sounds yet but check to see whether we've played the current one.
       for (var i = 0; i < playedSounds.length; i++)
           if (playedSounds[i] == sound)
               return true;

       // Note that we've now played this sound.
       playedSounds.push(sound);
       return false;

   }

   function playSounds() {

       var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (sounds.length));

       // Loop until we've found a sound that we've not yet played.
       while (hasPlayed(index)) {

           index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (sounds.length));

       }

       $("#element").html("<embed src=\"" + sounds[index] + "\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"true\" />");

   }
   ```

Comment: Do you know how to get this code to work on mobile and tablet browsers?

Comment: This is the code I'm using http://jsfiddle.net/adamsears/kZF9T/ - which won't work on mobile/tablet

Answer (score 0):

I would be tempted to do something like this ([JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/cbuckley/FdLge/)):

```
var sounds = [];

// Return the full list of URLs in random order
function getSounds() {
    return [
        'url1',
        'url2',
        'url3'
    ].sort(function () {
        // http://stackoverflow.com/a/18650169/283078
        return (.5 - Math.random());
    });
}

// Play the next sound
function playSound() {
    if (!sounds.length) {
        // Get the list of sounds (random order)
        sounds = getSounds();
    }

    // Pops a URL every time, ensuring all are played exactly once
    $("#element").html(
        '<embed src="' + sounds.pop() +
        '" hidden="true" autostart="true" />'
    );

    // Once all the URLs have been popped, the process starts again
}
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks a lot, it worked!
The only issue now is that the audio clips no longer autostart on page load. How could I solve this?

Comment: Have you tried [the updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cbuckley/FdLge/)? I've copied your embed code, so there shouldn't be any difference to the autostart.

Comment: Do you know how to get this type of code to work on mobile and tablet browsers?

Comment: You need a user interaction to start your audio, otherwise it won't autoplay: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13266474/autoplay-audio-on-mobile-safari

Comment: I have an image that users click to make the audio clip play, can I get the audio to play on mobile when they click the image like on desktop? - I don't mind losing the autoplay on mobile

Comment: This is the code I'm using http://jsfiddle.net/adamsears/kZF9T/ - which won't work on mobile/tablet

Comment: None of the examples (mine or others) are likely to work on mobile or tablet. You'd need to solve this in a *very* different way to work on mobile — see my linked question above. You'd need to start thinking about audio sprites, which makes the whole problem a lot more complicated. You should read some of the other SO questions on the topic, or ask another one yourself.