# Possible to reduce SoundManager 2 lag on Android?

Tags: android, soundmanager2

I've implemented SoundManager 2 on my webpage which all works fantastically well in every browser I've thrown at it so far.

When I test on desktop, there is very little lag between clicking the div and hearing the sound played.
However, on Android there is always a lag of about a second the first time the sound is played. After that, there is hardly any lag at all.

Is it possible to reduce or remove the first time played lag on Android?

Here is the code I'm using

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    soundManager.setup({
        url: 'www.mysite.com/swf/',
        preferFlash: false,
        onready: function() {
            soundManager.setup({
                defaultOptions: {
                    autoLoad: true,
                    autoPlay: false
                }
            });
            soundManager.createSound({
                id: 'mysound',
                url: 'www.mysite.com/sounds/mysound.mp3',
                volume: 50
            });
        }
    });


    $(document).on("click",".wrapper",function(e){
        soundManager.play('mysound');
    }

}
```

I've tried manually loading the sound like this

```
    var preload = soundManager.createSound({
        id: 'mysound',
        url: 'www.mysite.com/sounds/mysound.mp3',
        volume: 50
    });
    preload.load();
```

But that made no difference!

Anybody had this working without a lag on Android?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is to do with android's policy of only allowing sound to play in response to a user input.

eg: [Autoplay audio on mobile safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13266474/autoplay-audio-on-mobile-safari)

This is a limitation in mobile browsers.

the reason you have lag is from the fact that the sound has to load the first time you click. Your preloading does not work, as it is not run in response to user input, and is therefore blocked.

A solution would be to implement a welcome screen that loads the sound upon hitting an 'enter' button, as the top comment of the above link describes.

If you only need this to work on one browser you can navigate to

`chrome://flags/#disable-gesture-requirement-for-media-playback`

on your android phone and click Enable