# Soundcloud Stratus Player - Cross-platform compatibility

Tags: android, ios, soundcloud, soundcloud-stratus

I'm using Soundcloud's stratus player on the following page - http://www.naturesoundmap.com/

So far I'm very happy with it's functionality, but I've been getting reports from users that indicate there may be compatibility issues.

It's hard to isolate where the problem is exactly, and perhaps it's not the Soundcloud player at all, but we're getting reports from many iOS users that it takes unusually long to connect with Soundcloud - like minutes. I tested on Safari on an iPad mini & it was ok for me, then tested on a 10" iPad and the sounds wouldn't play at all.

I've tested on an Android using Chrome & the player is activated & the pause button indicates it is playing, but no sound. If I 'pause' then hit 'play' I get sound. On other browsers on Android it seems ok.

I haven't had any reports of problems from Windows users.

Question - Has anyone else has a similar experience &/or does anyone have any ideas how to resolve such issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is to do with mobiles' policy of only allowing sound to play in response to a user input.

eg: [Autoplay audio on mobile safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13266474/autoplay-audio-on-mobile-safari)

This is a limitation in mobile browsers.

Sound must be played in response to user interaction, hence why it automatically does not play, but does upon touching pause then play.

A solution would be to implement a welcome screen that loads the sound upon hitting an 'enter' button, as the top comment of the above link describes.