# Mixcloud Player autoplay not working on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, mobile

I want to put that page up where I have a selection of cloudcasts worth listening. And I want to launch them with a custom interface.

It works well on desktop, but *not at all on mobile devices*: the player won't start the playlist. It keeps on spinning and spinning and never starts.

The mixcloud team didn't reply to my question.

So, I have 2 codepen with 2 different techniques that I tried to make it work:

The first one employs the [Mixcloud Widget API](http://www.mixcloud.com/developers/widget/) and tries to invoke when ready the `player.play()` method.
It doesn't work on mobile, nor does `player.load("/some/tape", true)`.

Test it:
http://codepen.io/zipang/debug/KwVOpB

Full sources:
http://codepen.io/zipang/pen/KwVOpB

The second one uses a less subtile approach: it regenerates the iframe with the `autoplay=true` parameter and inserts it into the DOM.
With no further results on mobile.

Test it:
http://codepen.io/zipang/debug/azdQmR

Full sources:
http://codepen.io/zipang/pen/azdQmR

Does anyone know if there is a reason why? Or is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after some investigations, it is not a mixcloud player issue, but a more general one :

On mobile devices, any audio/video stream must be initiated by the user.

It's more a political choice than a technical issue.

Here is a list of other questions referring to the same issue (under many different appellations)

- ["Autoplay" HTML5 audio player on mobile browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26066062/autoplay-html5-audio-player-on-mobile-browsers?rq=1)
- [Youtube autoplay not working on mobile devices with embedded HTML5 player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15090782/youtube-autoplay-not-working-on-mobile-devices-with-embedded-html5-player?rq=1)
- [Audio tag bug(?) on Android Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11916451/audio-tag-bug-on-android-chrome?lq=1)
- [Soundcloud Stratus Player - Cross-platform compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21506721/soundcloud-stratus-player-cross-platform-compatibility/21508950#21508950)

And a lot more...

[EDITED]
I had a confirmation of this issue by the mixcloud team :

> Hi,
>
> It's not possible to auto play audio on mobile devices - none of the
>   browsers support it. You can only start playback within a click event
>   - so we can't make autoplay work with our widget, I'm afraid.
>
> Sam