# HTML: audio cannot be played in mobile browser

Tags: html

The HTML ***audio tag*** play works well on all browsers on computers i.e. desktop as well as laptop.

**HTML code.**

```
 echo "<audio controls autoplay='autoplay'><source src='images/audio.mp3'></audio>";
```

When it comes to mobile browsers, sound couldn't play eventhough I turned on browser notification. I have to press play button as shown in image below. How to make it auto start and hidden in mobile browser?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34837930/audio-tag-autoplay-not-working-in-mobile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Autoplay is not allowed in the mobile browsers. So it won't work.

If you must use audio in your app, then you can try this post

http://pupunzi.open-lab.com/2013/03/13/making-html5-audio-actually-work-on-mobile/