# sound in aframe virtual reality wont work on phone or laptop

Tags: html, aframe, virtual-reality

i don't know how to add background music on my virtual reality world, where it works on a mobile device (iPhone). it used to work on laptop but it doesn't anymore and it never worked on phone.
https://glitch.com/edit/#!/coral-fowl
https://coral-fowl.glitch.me/

Answer (score 0):

It does play but it has to download first. Your sound is more than 200 MB and it takes a long time. Pick a smaller audio file. Specially important in mobile where  resources are more constrained.

Comment: i changed it to a 39MB file. still wont work and my site keeps crashing saying "Aw snap, something went wrong with displaying this webpage."its  crashing on phone and laptop

Comment: Still too big. I would not go more than 2-3 MB max

Comment: There’s no audio autoplay in mobile. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34837930/audio-tag-autoplay-not-working-in-mobile