# How to ask for audio autoplay permission with javascript

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

I would like to ask a user permission (like the mic permission in for example google meet) to autoplay an audio file for a rickroll. I would like the javascript function to be played after the user accepts the permission.

This is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Not a rickroll</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body onload="rick();">
    <div class="everything">
      <h1>Loading....</h1>
      <audio id="rick" src="roll.mp3" autoplay preload="auto"></audio> 
    </div>
    <script src="sound.js">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is the javascript code:

```
var popupsound = document.getElementById("rick");

function rick() {
   popupsound.play(); //play the audio file
     // Change background to dancing rick
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('rick.gif')"

  // Hide the heading and the button
  document.querySelector(".everything").style.display = "none"
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think this question has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56834621/request-permission-to-automatically-play-an-audio-file).

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>permission microphone</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>sound autistar</h1>


  <script>

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
  audio: true,
}).then((stream) => {
  // Reproducir audio
  const audio = new Audio("alarm.mp3");
  audio.play();
});

  </script>
  <audio autoplay>
    <source src="alarm.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  </audio>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding a button that, when clicked, requests permission and then plays the audio.

```js
var popupsound = document.getElementById("rick");

function playAudio() {
  if (popupsound.paused) {
    popupsound.play();
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('rick.gif')";
    document.querySelector(".everything").style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Not a rickroll</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="everything">
      <h1>Loading....</h1>
      <button onclick="playAudio()">Click to Play</button>
      <audio id="rick" src="roll.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>
    </div>
    <script src="sound.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```