# Video in S3 bucket won't open on page load

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, video, react-component

I have a video in an Amazon S3 bucket. The video is around 6MB in size, has been made public, and is used as a background video for the homepage of my React application. I have applied the object URL directly to the video html element however when the React application loads, the video does not show. If I were to go to a different page and come back to the homepage, the video appears just fine.

Code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import black from '../../imgs/backgrounds/black.jpg';

class HeaderVideo extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <video poster={black} autoPlay={true} loop>
                <source src="https://beatsbyzero.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/videos/blackwhite1.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
            </video>
        )
    }
}

export default HeaderVideo;
```

Any ideas on how to handle this?

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue https://codesandbox.io/s/s3video-5y9ie?file=/src/components/HeaderVideo/HeaderVideo.js. It works.

Comment: try to make your own sandbox if issue isn't solved yet.

Comment: Your sandbox and mine (https://codesandbox.io/s/video-test-jbouq) both show on load, but for some reason in my project it doesn't seem to work locally or in my practice environment: http://mdberry721-001-site11.gtempurl.com/

Comment: can you share your git repo with project (that cantains minimal local code whitch broken) ?

Comment: Here is my repo: https://github.com/MDBerry/BeatsByZer0_V2/tree/master/BeatsByZer0_V2/ClientApp/src. All the action happens in "components/Elements" for HeaderVideo, "components/Sections" for TitleScreen and "components/Pages" for Homepage

Comment: Also, there is a const file in "consts/BackgroundVideosConst.js" that contains links to all the background videos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the root cause:
https://blog.chromium.org/2017/09/unified-autoplay.html

I prepared video for you (without sound track)
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lHGyoq-UHZ0YBHLY0-C_zf9yWkGgU2AZ/view?usp=sharing

Your video had a silent audio:

[image]

Now video hasn't audio:
[image]

Please, download video and replace it, then run your code.
I hope all be fine.

It can be helpful also:
[Browser denying javascript play()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57504122/browser-denying-javascript-play)

How to remove an audio track from an mp4 video file:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6402/how-to-remove-an-audio-track-from-an-mp4-video-file

Comment: While the exact steps provided didn't fix the issue exactly, this is very important knowledge and helped me find the issue. Please note that the audio problem mentioned in this answer was correct, but I also had to add the "muted" attribute to the <video> tag which fixed the issue. Marking this answer correct, thanks!