# How can I play an audio when a component is mounted on React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple notification component that looks like:

```
export const Notification = (props) => {
  return (
    blah blah
  );
}
```

It gets rendered when a push notification happens from the server. How can I play a notification sound when the Notification component gets rendered?

I have found many articles on how to programmatically play audios with the HTMLAudioElement creating a new Audio(src) and playing it when clicking a button or triggering other events. But not on how to trigger the audio when mounting a component on React. One would think this would be already over discussed on the internet, or maybe I over looked something? Thanks.

Comment: What about using a `useEffect`?

Comment: Browsers won't let you play any media using javascript unless the user has interacted with the page at least once.

Answer (score 0):

As @evolutionxbox mentions [`useEffect`](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/) is probably the route to go. It would look something like this.

```
const {useEffect} = React;

import wavFile from './path/to/file';

function Notification() {

  useEffect(() => {
    const audio = new Audio(wavFile);
    audio.play()
  }, []);

  return <div />

};
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. Yeah, of course I had tried an effect before. But what happened is that Chrome was blocking the play() method because of the new autoplay policies: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57504122/browser-denying-javascript-play. 
 https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes