# Texturing WebGL with “autoplay” video element — not working on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, html5-video, webgl, mobile-safari

I’m a contributor to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web), where there’s [an issue](https://github.com/mdn/content/issues/13775) that was raised about a code demo in the [Animating textures in WebGL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API/Tutorial/Animating_textures_in_WebGL) article.

In order to have a self-contained [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in this question, I’ve copied the demo code from that article into a runnable snippet here (below).

The demo creates a `video` element, sets the [`autoplay`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/autoplay) attribute on it, and then layers that video over a 3D rotating cube as a texture.

My question is: ***How can we make that demo code work as expected on iOS?***

##### Expected behavior

The expected behavior is for the browser to display a 3D rotating cube, with the video from https://mdn.github.io/dom-examples/webgl-examples/tutorial/sample8/Firefox.mp4 layered over the rotating cube as a texture — like this:

[image: MDN 3D rotating cube example, with video texture as expected]

…and in all current browsers on all platforms except for iOS, that is the actual behavior.

##### Actual behavior on iOS

On iOS, in Safari (mobile) — and I think in any other browsers running on iOS (since they all use WebKit as their engine) — a 3D rotating cube is displayed as expected; however, the video is not layered over the rotating cube as expected but instead the browser just displays a plain blue rotating cube, with no texture at all layered over it — like this:

[image: MDN 3D rotating cube example, without expected video texture]

##### Troubleshooting steps taken, and error messages seen

I don’t have iOS browser debugging tools myself, but an [issue comment](https://github.com/mdn/content/issues/13775#issuecomment-1065190991) from an MDN user says the browser logs this:

> setupVideo webgl-demo.js:141 — Unhandled Promise Rejection: NotAllowedError: The request is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context, possibly because the user denied permission.

> [image: browser error message]

Because the line numbers don’t match up directly, I’m not sure what’s a line 141 in the code as the iOS browser sees it — but https://github.com/mdn/dom-examples/blob/master/webgl-examples/tutorial/sample8/webgl-demo.js#L154 is my best guess — the `video.play()` call.

So the same [issue comment](https://github.com/mdn/content/issues/13775#issuecomment-1065190991) which quotes the above message also references [Browser denying javascript play()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57504122/browser-denying-javascript-play) as a related SO question.

…and that SO question cites a similar *“not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context, possibly because the user denied permission”* error message.

---

##### Runnable code snippet that doesn’t work as expected on iOS

```js
var cubeRotation = 0.0;
var copyVideo = false;

main();

function main() {
  const canvas = document.querySelector("#glcanvas");
  const gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");
  if (!gl) {
    alert(
      "Unable to initialize WebGL. Your browser or machine may not support it."
    );
    return;
  }
  const vsSource = `
    attribute vec4 aVertexPosition;
    attribute vec3 aVertexNormal;
    attribute vec2 aTextureCoord;

    uniform mat4 uNormalMatrix;
    uniform mat4 uModelViewMatrix;
    uniform mat4 uProjectionMatrix;

    varying highp vec2 vTextureCoord;
    varying highp vec3 vLighting;

    void main(void) {
      gl_Position = uProjectionMatrix * uModelViewMatrix * aVertexPosition;
      vTextureCoord = aTextureCoord;

      // Apply lighting effect

      highp vec3 ambientLight = vec3(0.3, 0.3, 0.3);
      highp vec3 directionalLightColor = vec3(1, 1, 1);
      highp vec3 directionalVector = normalize(vec3(0.85, 0.8, 0.75));

      highp vec4 transformedNormal = uNormalMatrix * vec4(aVertexNormal, 1.0);

      highp float directional = max(dot(transformedNormal.xyz, directionalVector), 0.0);
      vLighting = ambientLight + (directionalLightColor * directional);
    }
  `;
  const fsSource = `
    varying highp vec2 vTextureCoord;
    varying highp vec3 vLighting;

    uniform sampler2D uSampler;

    void main(void) {
      highp vec4 texelColor = texture2D(uSampler, vTextureCoord);

      gl_FragColor = vec4(texelColor.rgb * vLighting, texelColor.a);
    }
  `;

  const shaderProgram = initShaderProgram(gl, vsSource, fsSource);
  const programInfo = {
    program: shaderProgram,
    attribLocations: {
      vertexPosition: gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "aVertexPosition"),
      vertexNormal: gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "aVertexNormal"),
      textureCoord: gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "aTextureCoord"),
    },
    uniformLocations: {
      projectionMatrix: gl.getUniformLocation(
        shaderProgram,
        "uProjectionMatrix"
      ),
      modelViewMatrix: gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uModelViewMatrix"),
      normalMatrix: gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uNormalMatrix"),
      uSampler: gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uSampler"),
    },
  };

  const buffers = initBuffers(gl);
  const texture = initTexture(gl);
  const video = setupVideo("https://mdn.github.io/dom-examples/webgl-examples/tutorial/sample8/Firefox.mp4");
  var then = 0;

  function render(now) {
    now *= 0.001; // convert to seconds
    const deltaTime = now - then;
    then = now;
    if (copyVideo) {
      updateTexture(gl, texture, video);
    }
    drawScene(gl, programInfo, buffers, texture, deltaTime);
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

function setupVideo(url) {
  const video = document.createElement("video");
  var playing = false;
  var timeupdate = false;
  video.muted = true;
  video.autoplay = true;
  video.loop = true;
  video.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
  video.addEventListener(
    "playing",
    function () {
      playing = true;
      checkReady();
    },
    true
  );
  video.addEventListener(
    "timeupdate",
    function () {
      timeupdate = true;
      checkReady();
    },
    true
  );
  video.src = url;
  video.play();
  function checkReady() {
    if (playing && timeupdate) {
      copyVideo = true;
    }
  }
  return video;
}

function initBuffers(gl) {
  const positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
  const positions = [
    -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
    -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
    -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0,
    -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0,
    1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0,
    -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0,
  ];
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(positions), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
  const normalBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, normalBuffer);

  const vertexNormals = [
    0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
    0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0,
    0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
    0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0,
    1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
    -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
  ];

  gl.bufferData(
    gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,
    new Float32Array(vertexNormals),
    gl.STATIC_DRAW
  );
  const textureCoordBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, textureCoordBuffer);
  const textureCoordinates = [
    0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0,
    0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0,
    0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0,
    0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0,
    0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0,
    0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0,
  ];
  gl.bufferData(
    gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,
    new Float32Array(textureCoordinates),
    gl.STATIC_DRAW
  );
  const indexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer);
  const indices = [
    0,
    1,
    2,
    0,
    2,
    3, // front
    4,
    5,
    6,
    4,
    6,
    7, // back
    8,
    9,
    10,
    8,
    10,
    11, // top
    12,
    13,
    14,
    12,
    14,
    15, // bottom
    16,
    17,
    18,
    16,
    18,
    19, // right
    20,
    21,
    22,
    20,
    22,
    23, // left
  ];
  gl.bufferData(
    gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,
    new Uint16Array(indices),
    gl.STATIC_DRAW
  );
  return {
    position: positionBuffer,
    normal: normalBuffer,
    textureCoord: textureCoordBuffer,
    indices: indexBuffer,
  };
}

function initTexture(gl, url) {
  const texture = gl.createTexture();
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
  const level = 0;
  const internalFormat = gl.RGBA;
  const width = 1;
  const height = 1;
  const border = 0;
  const srcFormat = gl.RGBA;
  const srcType = gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE;
  const pixel = new Uint8Array([0, 0, 255, 255]); // opaque blue
  gl.texImage2D(
    gl.TEXTURE_2D,
    level,
    internalFormat,
    width,
    height,
    border,
    srcFormat,
    srcType,
    pixel
  );
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);

  return texture;
}

function updateTexture(gl, texture, video) {
  const level = 0;
  const internalFormat = gl.RGBA;
  const srcFormat = gl.RGBA;
  const srcType = gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE;
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
  gl.texImage2D(
    gl.TEXTURE_2D,
    level,
    internalFormat,
    srcFormat,
    srcType,
    video
  );
}

function isPowerOf2(value) {
  return (value & (value - 1)) == 0;
}

function drawScene(gl, programInfo, buffers, texture, deltaTime) {
  gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0); // Clear to black, fully opaque
  gl.clearDepth(1.0); // Clear everything
  gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST); // Enable depth testing
  gl.depthFunc(gl.LEQUAL); // Near things obscure far things
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
  const fieldOfView = (45 * Math.PI) / 180; // in radians
  const aspect = gl.canvas.clientWidth / gl.canvas.clientHeight;
  const zNear = 0.1;
  const zFar = 100.0;
  const projectionMatrix = mat4.create();
  mat4.perspective(projectionMatrix, fieldOfView, aspect, zNear, zFar);
  const modelViewMatrix = mat4.create();
  mat4.translate(
    modelViewMatrix, // destination matrix
    modelViewMatrix, // matrix to translate
    [-0.0, 0.0, -6.0]
  ); // amount to translate
  mat4.rotate(
    modelViewMatrix, // destination matrix
    modelViewMatrix, // matrix to rotate
    cubeRotation, // amount to rotate in radians
    [0, 0, 1]
  ); // axis to rotate around (Z)
  mat4.rotate(
    modelViewMatrix, // destination matrix
    modelViewMatrix, // matrix to rotate
    cubeRotation * 0.7, // amount to rotate in radians
    [0, 1, 0]
  ); // axis to rotate around (X)

  const normalMatrix = mat4.create();
  mat4.invert(normalMatrix, modelViewMatrix);
  mat4.transpose(normalMatrix, normalMatrix);
  {
    const numComponents = 3;
    const type = gl.FLOAT;
    const normalize = false;
    const stride = 0;
    const offset = 0;
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers.position);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(
      programInfo.attribLocations.vertexPosition,
      numComponents,
      type,
      normalize,
      stride,
      offset
    );
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(programInfo.attribLocations.vertexPosition);
  }
  {
    const numComponents = 2;
    const type = gl.FLOAT;
    const normalize = false;
    const stride = 0;
    const offset = 0;
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers.textureCoord);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(
      programInfo.attribLocations.textureCoord,
      numComponents,
      type,
      normalize,
      stride,
      offset
    );
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(programInfo.attribLocations.textureCoord);
  }
  {
    const numComponents = 3;
    const type = gl.FLOAT;
    const normalize = false;
    const stride = 0;
    const offset = 0;
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers.normal);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(
      programInfo.attribLocations.vertexNormal,
      numComponents,
      type,
      normalize,
      stride,
      offset
    );
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(programInfo.attribLocations.vertexNormal);
  }

  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers.indices);
  gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);
  gl.uniformMatrix4fv(
    programInfo.uniformLocations.projectionMatrix,
    false,
    projectionMatrix
  );
  gl.uniformMatrix4fv(
    programInfo.uniformLocations.modelViewMatrix,
    false,
    modelViewMatrix
  );
  gl.uniformMatrix4fv(
    programInfo.uniformLocations.normalMatrix,
    false,
    normalMatrix
  );
  gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
  gl.uniform1i(programInfo.uniformLocations.uSampler, 0);
  {
    const vertexCount = 36;
    const type = gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT;
    const offset = 0;
    gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, vertexCount, type, offset);
  }
  cubeRotation += deltaTime;
}

function initShaderProgram(gl, vsSource, fsSource) {
  const vertexShader = loadShader(gl, gl.VERTEX_SHADER, vsSource);
  const fragmentShader = loadShader(gl, gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER, fsSource);
  const shaderProgram = gl.createProgram();
  gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
  gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
  gl.linkProgram(shaderProgram);
  if (!gl.getProgramParameter(shaderProgram, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
    alert(
      "Unable to initialize the shader program: " +
        gl.getProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram)
    );
    return null;
  }

  return shaderProgram;
}

function loadShader(gl, type, source) {
  const shader = gl.createShader(type);
  gl.shaderSource(shader, source);
  gl.compileShader(shader);
  if (!gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
    alert(
      "An error occurred compiling the shaders: " + gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader)
    );
    gl.deleteShader(shader);
    return null;
  }
  return shader;
}
```

```css
canvas { border: 2px solid black; background-color: black; }
video { display: none; }
```

```html
<!doctype html><meta charset="utf-8"><title>WebGL Demo</title>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gl-matrix/2.8.1/gl-matrix-min.js"></script>
<canvas id="glcanvas" width="640" height="480"></canvas>
```

Comment: That demo on MDN runs in an `iframe` on different origin, maybe the `allow="autoplay"` attribute on that `iframe` would help?

Comment: @syduki The standalone demo at https://mdn.github.io/dom-examples/webgl-examples/tutorial/sample8/ — exact same code, but just in a page of its own rather than in an `iframe` — also doesn’t show the video texture as expected on iOS. So it seems like the framing must not be the root problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution:** Drop the `autoplay` attribute, and add the [`playsInline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#attr-playsinline) attribute.

The clue on `playsInline` came from https://stackoverflow.com/a/65965158/441757.

The realization on `autoplay` came from trial-and-error — by dropping it to see what’d happen.

And what happens is that without that attribute set, the demo still continues to work in all other browsers as expected — but then also works as expected on iOS too.

So it seems: when using a video as a WebGL texture, it’s unnecessary to set `autoplay` to get the video to play — but it *is* necessary to set [`playsInline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#attr-playsinline) to make it work on iOS.

---

##### Runnable snippet that works in all browsers — including on iOS

```js
var cubeRotation = 0.0;
var copyVideo = false;

main();

function main() {
  const canvas = document.querySelector("#glcanvas");
  const gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");
  if (!gl) {
    alert(
      "Unable to initialize WebGL. Your browser or machine may not support it."
    );
    return;
  }
  const vsSource = `
    attribute vec4 aVertexPosition;
    attribute vec3 aVertexNormal;
    attribute vec2 aTextureCoord;

    uniform mat4 uNormalMatrix;
    uniform mat4 uModelViewMatrix;
    uniform mat4 uProjectionMatrix;

    varying highp vec2 vTextureCoord;
    varying highp vec3 vLighting;

    void main(void) {
      gl_Position = uProjectionMatrix * uModelViewMatrix * aVertexPosition;
      vTextureCoord = aTextureCoord;

      // Apply lighting effect

      highp vec3 ambientLight = vec3(0.3, 0.3, 0.3);
      highp vec3 directionalLightColor = vec3(1, 1, 1);
      highp vec3 directionalVector = normalize(vec3(0.85, 0.8, 0.75));

      highp vec4 transformedNormal = uNormalMatrix * vec4(aVertexNormal, 1.0);

      highp float directional = max(dot(transformedNormal.xyz, directionalVector), 0.0);
      vLighting = ambientLight + (directionalLightColor * directional);
    }
  `;
  const fsSource = `
    varying highp vec2 vTextureCoord;
    varying highp vec3 vLighting;

    uniform sampler2D uSampler;

    void main(void) {
      highp vec4 texelColor = texture2D(uSampler, vTextureCoord);

      gl_FragColor = vec4(texelColor.rgb * vLighting, texelColor.a);
    }
  `;

  const shaderProgram = initShaderProgram(gl, vsSource, fsSource);
  const programInfo = {
    program: shaderProgram,
    attribLocations: {
      vertexPosition: gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "aVertexPosition"),
      vertexNormal: gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "aVertexNormal"),
      textureCoord: gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "aTextureCoord"),
    },
    uniformLocations: {
      projectionMatrix: gl.getUniformLocation(
        shaderProgram,
        "uProjectionMatrix"
      ),
      modelViewMatrix: gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uModelViewMatrix"),
      normalMatrix: gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uNormalMatrix"),
      uSampler: gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uSampler"),
    },
  };

  const buffers = initBuffers(gl);
  const texture = initTexture(gl);
  const video = setupVideo("https://mdn.github.io/dom-examples/webgl-examples/tutorial/sample8/Firefox.mp4");
  var then = 0;

  function render(now) {
    now *= 0.001; // convert to seconds
    const deltaTime = now - then;
    then = now;
    if (copyVideo) {
      updateTexture(gl, texture, video);
    }
    drawScene(gl, programInfo, buffers, texture, deltaTime);
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

function setupVideo(url) {
  const video = document.createElement("video");
  var playing = false;
  var timeupdate = false;
  video.muted = true;
  video.playsInline = true;
  video.loop = true;
  video.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
  video.addEventListener(
    "playing",
    function () {
      playing = true;
      checkReady();
    },
    true
  );
  video.addEventListener(
    "timeupdate",
    function () {
      timeupdate = true;
      checkReady();
    },
    true
  );
  video.src = url;
  video.play();
  function checkReady() {
    if (playing && timeupdate) {
      copyVideo = true;
    }
  }
  return video;
}

function initBuffers(gl) {
  const positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
  const positions = [
    -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
    -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
    -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0,
    -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0,
    1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0,
    -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0,
  ];
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(positions), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
  const normalBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, normalBuffer);

  const vertexNormals = [
    0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
    0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0,
    0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
    0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0,
    1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
    -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
  ];

  gl.bufferData(
    gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,
    new Float32Array(vertexNormals),
    gl.STATIC_DRAW
  );
  const textureCoordBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, textureCoordBuffer);
  const textureCoordinates = [
    0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0,
    0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0,
    0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0,
    0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0,
    0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0,
    0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0,
  ];
  gl.bufferData(
    gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,
    new Float32Array(textureCoordinates),
    gl.STATIC_DRAW
  );
  const indexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer);
  const indices = [
    0,
    1,
    2,
    0,
    2,
    3, // front
    4,
    5,
    6,
    4,
    6,
    7, // back
    8,
    9,
    10,
    8,
    10,
    11, // top
    12,
    13,
    14,
    12,
    14,
    15, // bottom
    16,
    17,
    18,
    16,
    18,
    19, // right
    20,
    21,
    22,
    20,
    22,
    23, // left
  ];
  gl.bufferData(
    gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,
    new Uint16Array(indices),
    gl.STATIC_DRAW
  );
  return {
    position: positionBuffer,
    normal: normalBuffer,
    textureCoord: textureCoordBuffer,
    indices: indexBuffer,
  };
}

function initTexture(gl, url) {
  const texture = gl.createTexture();
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
  const level = 0;
  const internalFormat = gl.RGBA;
  const width = 1;
  const height = 1;
  const border = 0;
  const srcFormat = gl.RGBA;
  const srcType = gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE;
  const pixel = new Uint8Array([0, 0, 255, 255]); // opaque blue
  gl.texImage2D(
    gl.TEXTURE_2D,
    level,
    internalFormat,
    width,
    height,
    border,
    srcFormat,
    srcType,
    pixel
  );
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);

  return texture;
}

function updateTexture(gl, texture, video) {
  const level = 0;
  const internalFormat = gl.RGBA;
  const srcFormat = gl.RGBA;
  const srcType = gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE;
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
  gl.texImage2D(
    gl.TEXTURE_2D,
    level,
    internalFormat,
    srcFormat,
    srcType,
    video
  );
}

function isPowerOf2(value) {
  return (value & (value - 1)) == 0;
}

function drawScene(gl, programInfo, buffers, texture, deltaTime) {
  gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0); // Clear to black, fully opaque
  gl.clearDepth(1.0); // Clear everything
  gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST); // Enable depth testing
  gl.depthFunc(gl.LEQUAL); // Near things obscure far things
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
  const fieldOfView = (45 * Math.PI) / 180; // in radians
  const aspect = gl.canvas.clientWidth / gl.canvas.clientHeight;
  const zNear = 0.1;
  const zFar = 100.0;
  const projectionMatrix = mat4.create();
  mat4.perspective(projectionMatrix, fieldOfView, aspect, zNear, zFar);
  const modelViewMatrix = mat4.create();
  mat4.translate(
    modelViewMatrix, // destination matrix
    modelViewMatrix, // matrix to translate
    [-0.0, 0.0, -6.0]
  ); // amount to translate
  mat4.rotate(
    modelViewMatrix, // destination matrix
    modelViewMatrix, // matrix to rotate
    cubeRotation, // amount to rotate in radians
    [0, 0, 1]
  ); // axis to rotate around (Z)
  mat4.rotate(
    modelViewMatrix, // destination matrix
    modelViewMatrix, // matrix to rotate
    cubeRotation * 0.7, // amount to rotate in radians
    [0, 1, 0]
  ); // axis to rotate around (X)

  const normalMatrix = mat4.create();
  mat4.invert(normalMatrix, modelViewMatrix);
  mat4.transpose(normalMatrix, normalMatrix);
  {
    const numComponents = 3;
    const type = gl.FLOAT;
    const normalize = false;
    const stride = 0;
    const offset = 0;
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers.position);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(
      programInfo.attribLocations.vertexPosition,
      numComponents,
      type,
      normalize,
      stride,
      offset
    );
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(programInfo.attribLocations.vertexPosition);
  }
  {
    const numComponents = 2;
    const type = gl.FLOAT;
    const normalize = false;
    const stride = 0;
    const offset = 0;
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers.textureCoord);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(
      programInfo.attribLocations.textureCoord,
      numComponents,
      type,
      normalize,
      stride,
      offset
    );
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(programInfo.attribLocations.textureCoord);
  }
  {
    const numComponents = 3;
    const type = gl.FLOAT;
    const normalize = false;
    const stride = 0;
    const offset = 0;
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers.normal);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(
      programInfo.attribLocations.vertexNormal,
      numComponents,
      type,
      normalize,
      stride,
      offset
    );
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(programInfo.attribLocations.vertexNormal);
  }

  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers.indices);
  gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);
  gl.uniformMatrix4fv(
    programInfo.uniformLocations.projectionMatrix,
    false,
    projectionMatrix
  );
  gl.uniformMatrix4fv(
    programInfo.uniformLocations.modelViewMatrix,
    false,
    modelViewMatrix
  );
  gl.uniformMatrix4fv(
    programInfo.uniformLocations.normalMatrix,
    false,
    normalMatrix
  );
  gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
  gl.uniform1i(programInfo.uniformLocations.uSampler, 0);
  {
    const vertexCount = 36;
    const type = gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT;
    const offset = 0;
    gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, vertexCount, type, offset);
  }
  cubeRotation += deltaTime;
}

function initShaderProgram(gl, vsSource, fsSource) {
  const vertexShader = loadShader(gl, gl.VERTEX_SHADER, vsSource);
  const fragmentShader = loadShader(gl, gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER, fsSource);
  const shaderProgram = gl.createProgram();
  gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
  gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
  gl.linkProgram(shaderProgram);
  if (!gl.getProgramParameter(shaderProgram, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
    alert(
      "Unable to initialize the shader program: " +
        gl.getProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram)
    );
    return null;
  }

  return shaderProgram;
}

function loadShader(gl, type, source) {
  const shader = gl.createShader(type);
  gl.shaderSource(shader, source);
  gl.compileShader(shader);
  if (!gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
    alert(
      "An error occurred compiling the shaders: " + gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader)
    );
    gl.deleteShader(shader);
    return null;
  }
  return shader;
}
```

```css
canvas { border: 2px solid black; background-color: black; }
video { display: none; }
```

```html
<!doctype html><meta charset="utf-8"><title>WebGL Demo</title>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gl-matrix/2.8.1/gl-matrix-min.js"></script>
<canvas id="glcanvas" width="640" height="480"></canvas>
```