# How to play a video in the background on iOS Safari

Tags: javascript, html, ios, safari, html5-video

I am trying to play a video on a `canvas`, and by this I can control the area of the video that is displayed.

I can achieve this on desktop or Android browsers. However, on iOS Safari, I can not play a video that is hidden. When I call `play()` method on a video element (which I have to register on a user-trigger event callback), the video player will pop up at the very top layer of the webpage, even if the video element is **NOT** appended to the document, and after I close this player, the video will be paused.

Is there a way to disable this poped player and just play the video in the background?

Answer (score 3):

After I searched for the Safari related security policy, I found [this post](https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/) from webkit.

According to the policy, I can use `playsinline` to get rid of the fullscreen player. However `video.playsinline = true;` won't work, and `video.setAttribute("playsinline", true);` will do the trick. They say this property is a standard one now and I have no idea why I still have to use `setAttribute`. After this, I can set the `video` invisible with css like other browsers.

Btw, set the video muted will make the `autoplay` attribute taking effect.

Comment: Try `video.playsInline = true`. See https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/media.html#dom-video-playsinline — the IDL (JavaScript/DOM) attribute is `playsInline` (with a capital `I`), while the content attribute (HTML markup attribute) is `playsinline` (all lowercase).

Comment: Incidentally, I ran into a similar problem myself — see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73236080/texturing-webgl-with-autoplay-video-element-not-working-on-ios — and the solution was basically the same that you found.

Comment: @sideshowbarker `playsInline` is correct, thanks a lot. It is very strange that they always use all-lower-case but camalcase here.

Comment: @sideshowbarker It really took time to find the solution since I am using Windows currently and the dev tools support is so bad.

Comment: Perfect, had the same problem with the "poped up player" and adding `playsinline` fixed the issue.