# HTML5 - how to autoplay video tag on mobile browser?

Tags: html, css

[image]

this screenshot on mobile, the video doesn't autoplay even when i click on the play arrow button(which shouldn't even be there) still doesn't play at all, its like a picture but on desktop it's perfectly fine.

I tried this code

```
 <video preload autoplay loop muted defaultMuted playsinline>
    <source src="video2.mp4" type="video/mp4">

    </video>
```

but still no

Comment: Can you link to an example, or try and recreate something in jsfiddle or codebin etc? Do you mean this is working on desktop?

Comment: Does this answer your question : https://stackoverflow.com/q/34837930/9283958

Comment: @lharby testwebsitee98.000webhostapp.com , yes it works on desktop but not mobile

Comment: When you say "mobile browser", which browsers have you tested - Chrome, Safari, Firefox, etc?

Comment: @IMSoP Safari, firefox on ios 11

Comment: thats a default setting of mobile browser to prevent autoplay of videos to save mobile data usage. There is nothing you can do on Android as the user needs to enable it in their browser. For iOS you can use `<video playsinline>`

Comment: @tacoshy what if the user is using wifi on phone?

Comment: still remains a brwoser setting that will disable an autoplay by default.

Comment: anyway, you shouldn't try to get past it - what about the users that dont like things moving around?