# MP3 audio player HTML

Tags: html, html5-audio

I'm creating a website using wordpress and I'm trying to add a MP3 music into it.

But the music don't autoplay on mobile. And when I click on pause, the music stop, but if I scroll (on PC or mobile) the music start again and again and again.

Here the html code :

```
<figure>
<audio
    controls
    src="https://www.blog-motivation.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/ولنبلونكم-بشئ-من-الخوف-والجوع-ونقص-من-الاموال-والانفس-والثمرات-وبشر-الصابرين-اسلام-صبحي.mp3" autoplay>
  
</audio>
```

thank you

Answer (score 0):

It is to not use autoplay because it could disturb some peoples, but if you want your audio with autoplay it is better to put source to another tag like this:

```
<audio controls autoplay>
  <source src="https://www.blog-motivation.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/ولنبلونكم-بشئ-من-الخوف-والجوع-ونقص-من-الاموال-والانفس-والثمرات-وبشر-الصابرين-اسلام-صبحي.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

It is also possible that your bowser is Chrome and this browser blocs automatically autoplay. To control autoplay in Chrome go [here](https://www.ghacks.net/2018/02/06/how-to-control-audio-and-video-autoplay-in-google-chrome/).

Answer (score 0):

Refer here : [Audio Tag Autoplay Not working in mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34837930/audio-tag-autoplay-not-working-in-mobile)

Seems autoplay in chrome we need to use resume. it works in Firefox / chrome and target mobile / browser devices.