# Why is my audio tag not working on mobile browsers?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio, web-audio-api

My tag audio not function on mobile browsers, my code is the next:

Use different examples but not function [Audio Tag Autoplay Not working in mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34837930/audio-tag-autoplay-not-working-in-mobile)

Comment: Does [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Autoplay_guide#autoplay_availability) answer your question? As an (important) aside, you can edit your question, and add your comment there. There's no need to post additional questions as comments to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Autoplay is not supported on mobile browsers because it's too disruptive. Video has an option to autoplay if they are also muted. Google says "autoplay is still disabled on Chrome on Android, because muted autoplay doesn't make much sense for audio."

Ref: https://developer.chrome.com/blog/autoplay-2/