# Autoplay audio-file in safari

Tags: html, audio

I need to auto-play an audio file in safari 11/12.

The audio-tag:

```
<audio autoplay="true">
  <source src="camera.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Safari is not auto-playing the sound. I just found an article about auto-play audio in chrome:
[How to make audio autoplay on chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50490304/how-to-make-audio-autoplay-on-chrome)

But is there also a solution for the safari browsers?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13266474/autoplay-audio-on-mobile-safari

Comment: Its not about mobiles its about the safari browsers verison 11/12